# Navigation bar child function call from parent funtional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two components, a parent functional component, and a child class component. I am calling a function from the child class component in the parent functional component. Below is what I have tried and the error message I got. I think I'm missing something small but not sure what it is would appreciate any help.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'childRef.current.setModalOpen')

The Parent Functional Component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Child from './screens/Child';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
const childRef = useRef();

handleShowModal = () => {
  <Child ref={childRef}/>
  childRef.current.setModalOpen();
}

return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Punt Repair Header"
      component={Child}
      options={{
        headerRight: () => (
          <Icon style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            name='plus'
            size={30}
            onPress={() => handleShowModal()}
          />
        ),
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  )
  }
  export default App;
```

Child Class Component:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Modal } from 'react-native';

 class Child extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        modalOpen: false
    }
 }

 render() {
    setModalOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ modalOpen:true });
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Modal visible={this.state.modalOpen} animationType='slide'>
                <View>
                    <Text>Model Content</Text>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>

    );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't generally call a child's method from the parent, and you can't directly set the child component's state from the parent.

I think you will need to store `modalOpen` in the parent's state (so you will need to add state to the parent -- it can't be a stateless functional component) and then pass it as a prop down to the child.

So `handleShowModal` becomes

```
handleShowModal = () => {
  this.setState({showModal: true});
}
```

and when you call the child it looks like

```
<Icon style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
    name='plus'
    size={30}
    onPress={() => handleShowModal()}
    showModal={this.state.showModal}
/>
```

If there is some piece of data that you want both components to be able to manipulate, then it should go in Redux (or whatever overall state system you're using).

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Hollingsworth, I'll change the component to stateful and add your suggestion.